# Custom member route: :id not being included in route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created the following route:

```
    resource :tweets, only: [:create]
```

I then wanted to create an API for marking tweets as spam, so I modified my route as follows:

```
    resource :tweets, only: [:create] do
      get :spam, on: :member
    end
```

Despite designating this as a member route, it is not allowing me to include the :id field for the tweet.

[image]

I want the route to be:

```
/tweets/:id/spam
```

Instead of `/tweets/spam`

I read the rails guides and thought that marking this custom route as `member: :on` would automatically add the `:id` field. How do I add the `:id` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route should look like:

```
resources :tweets, only: [:create] do
   get :spam, on: :member
end
```

When you define resource (in singular) you're basically saying that you don't want to reference an ID